# Kaminari with Rails 3 not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I realise paginating with Kaminari is supposed to be simple, but I seem to be missing something...

My guidelines_controller.rb index action is

```
def index
    if params[:search].present?
    @search = Sunspot.search(Guideline) do  
      fulltext params[:search]
    end
    @guidelines = @search.results
  else

    @guidelines = Guideline.order(:title).page(params[:page])
  end
```

and I've added to views/guidelines/index.html.erb

```
<%= paginate @guidelines %>
```

But nothing is showing on my index page (Kaminari is bundled successfully).  What am I missing?

Comment: whats @guidelines show with out .page(params[:page]) ?

Comment: previously I had @guidelines = Guidelines.order(:title).all and it was displaying the guidelines in alphabetical order.  It's still displaying the same as that

Comment: did you set your route?

Comment: the route was already set to get 'guidelines', to: 'guidelines#index', as: :guidelines  should it change?

Comment: How many guidelines do you have? Maybe it is not enough for kaminari. Try to use `per(1)` scope.

Comment: Sergey you were absolutely right - on my locahost I didn't have enough guidelines for kaminari.  Genius, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per Sergey Kishenin - I didn't have enough guidelines on my local database for kaminari.  Adding per(1) scope made all the difference.